# Smooth Y-Axis object rotation in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, smoothing

I turned on the Input System & refactored my code in my project and noticed that when I move the mouse my character "lags" when moving the mouse slowly - as if the camera jumps from one position to another instead of moving smoothly.

So I want to make it so that moving the camera and the character is smooth but I have a problem.

I managed to make the camera moving smoothly on the X-axis, but I can't manage to make the character rotate smoothly on the Y-axis.

My current code responsible for rotating the camera and the character:

```
private void MovePlayerCamera()
    {
        // Get Y axis rotation and apply to capsule "player" (doesn't smooth rotation but i need to smooth it)
        float yRotation = playerMouseInput.x * sensitivity;
        transform.Rotate(0f, yRotation, 0f);

        // Apply Mouse Sensitivity & clamp xRotation so camera doesn't flip upside down
        xRotation -= playerMouseInput.y * sensitivity;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -lowerMaxRotation, upperMaxRotation);

        // Setup a camera rotation goal and apply to player (this smoothing code works)
        Quaternion goal = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        cameraPivot.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cameraPivot.localRotation, goal, cameraSmoothingStrength * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

I have already tried:

```
        // Get Y axis rotation and apply to object (with this code player just rotates to right by itself)
        float yRotation = playerMouseInput.x * sensitivity;
        transform.Rotate(0f, Mathf.Lerp(transform.rotation.y, yRotation, cameraSmoothingStrength * Time.deltaTime), 0f);
```

But it doesn't work - The character rotates to the right side by itself :(

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
private float targetYRotation;

private void MovePlayerCamera()
{
    // Get Y axis rotation and store it as targetYRotation
    float yRotation = playerMouseInput.x * sensitivity;
    targetYRotation += yRotation;

    // Smoothly interpolate the current rotation to the targetYRotation
    Quaternion currentYRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion targetYRotationQuat = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetYRotation, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentYRotation, targetYRotationQuat, cameraSmoothingStrength * Time.deltaTime);

    // Apply Mouse Sensitivity & clamp xRotation so camera doesn't flip upside down
    xRotation -= playerMouseInput.y * sensitivity;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -lowerMaxRotation, upperMaxRotation);

    // Setup a camera rotation goal and apply to player (this smoothing code works)
    Quaternion goal = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    cameraPivot.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cameraPivot.localRotation, goal, cameraSmoothingStrength * Time.deltaTime);
}
```